# DateTime.ParseExact throws System.FormatException

Tags: c#, datetime

Why this line of code **sometimes** throws `System.FormatException`?

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: How does something containing '/' match something containing '.'? Have you even tried something?

Comment: Sometimes this code doesn't throw any exceptions. Read some of below answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your string and format doesn't match.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

Use `dd.MM.yyyy` format instead.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014",
                                 "dd.MM.yyyy",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/FlqhWg)</kbd>.

Remember, [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning in custom date and time formats. It means as; *replace me with the current culture date separator*.

In your profile, it says you are from Azerbaijan. That means your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) is probably `az-Cyrl-AZ` (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan) or `az-Latn-AZ` (Latin, Azerbaijan).

*Actually*, doesn't matter which culture you use on this case because both culture has `.` as a [`DateSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx).

That means your original code also works with your `CurrentCulture`.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014",
                                 "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
                                 // or you can use null
```

For more information, take a look;

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You need a culture where `"."` is the `DateSeparator`, for example:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("az-Cyrl-AZ"));
```

if you are in Azerbaijan and use Azerbaijani language with the Cyrillic script.

You can use:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", "dd/MM/yyyy",
    null);
```

to just take the current culture.

Maybe you just need `"d"` instead of the verbose `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, since the standard short date format in Azerbaijani is just like `"01.07.2014"`.

The "invariant culture" uses `"/"` as its `DateSeparator`, so therefore you should not use it in your case.

Also, this works:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", "dd/MM/yyyy",
    new DateTimeFormatInfo { DateSeparator = ".", }
    );
```

because `new DateTimeFormatInfo()` makes a read/write "invariant-culture" date/time info for which you can change the relevant property.

Comment: Thanks. "az-Latn-AZ" - this one is more useful, as we use Latin script nowadays.

Comment: @gdrt94 Great. Both have the same `DateSeparator`: `"."` If your application is known to always use `"az-Latn-AZ"`, you can just type `null`. If there is a risk the current culture could be anything, write out `new CultureInfo("az-Latn-AZ")`.

Comment: @gdrt In fact I just changed `new CultureInfo("az-Cyrl-AZ")` into `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("az-Cyrl-AZ")` for two reasons: (1) You do not create a new instance of `CultureInfo` each time (to become garbage right after use) but pick the instance from a cache instead. (2) You get an instance with `UseUserOverride` set to False, so that a user with another preference for the date separator (who has changed the setting in Windows on his machine) will not break your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `/` in the date format will match the date separator of the culture that you specify. If you use a culture that has period as date separator, the parsing will work.

Example:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de"));
```

You can also use a literal period instead of the date separator specificer, then it works with the invariant culture:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Ref: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The format you have is different from the string provided:

Try either of the below, it will work :)

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact("01/07/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Your separator in date is `.` while in string format it is `/`

**Solution:**

Your format should be `"dd.MM.yyyy"` or `"MM.dd.yyyy"` as your date is `"01.07.2014"`. `01` and `07` exist both as date and month.

**This date can be `01st July 2014` or `07 Jan 2014`.**

Your code should be

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", 
                                 "dd.MM.yyyy", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

OR

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("01.07.2014", 
                                 "MM.dd.yyyy", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```